# Re: How to dynamically create a background worker in vb net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a follow-on question about this question:

[How to dynamically create a background worker in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376972/how-to-dynamically-create-a-background-worker-in-vb-net)

I'm afraid I don't understand how DirectCast would solve my problem. I am creating an array of backgroundworkers: bWorker(0), bWorker (1), etc. each one creates a new form which is also in an array: page(0), page(1) etc.

The background workers need to 'know' their index number so that they can create the appropriate page (which is a form). As I mentioned before, I have found a system that works. I put the backgroundworkers' hashcodes in an array which I use to retrieve their index numbers. It just feels a bit clunky and maybe using DirectCast would be better but I don't understand how.

Comment: I'm probably ignorant of something fundamental here. I don't know how I can use a reference to the object to define the index of the object created by the background worker. The backgroundworkers all use the same 2 subs:

Answer (score 1):

`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync` has **two overloads**. See [`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Now you can **pass a variable and get it** on `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` using [`DoWorkEventArgs.Argument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim BackgroundWorker1 As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
AddHandler BackgroundWorker1.DoWork, AddressOf BackgroundWorker_DoWork
Dim BackgroundWorker2 As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
AddHandler BackgroundWorker2.DoWork, AddressOf BackgroundWorker_DoWork
' I'm going to pass integers, but you can pass whatever you want.
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(0)
BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync(1)

Private Sub BackgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    Select Case e.Argument
        Case 0
            ' Form1
        Case 1
            ' Form2
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is the number of new forms to create can vary from 1 to 100. I would need to write case 100 times? I'm not sure if that's better than my current system.

Comment: They are pages of music each contains up to 192 user controls which in turn contain a large number of objects that represent notes etc. The music is played and its progress is tracked on each page. The backgroundworkers continue to create and fill pages after the music has started playing.

Comment: What's your current system?

Comment: I create an array of backgroundworkers which I redim according to the number of pages. I put the hashcode of each backgroundworker into an array: Dim HashList as Long : For i As Integer = 0 To PagineTotale
            HashList(i) = bWorker2(i).GetHashCode
            bWorker2(i).RunWorkerAsync()
        Next

Comment: I then use this:  Private Function HashToNumber(ByVal HashCode)
        Dim Pos As Byte
        For i As Integer = 0 To HashList.Length - 1
            If HashList(i) = HashCode Then
                Pos = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Return Pos
    End Function  to retrieve the index of the sender

Comment: L'utilizzo del blocco `Select Case` era solo un esempio, se ti serve  il semplice valore intero non vedo quale sia il problema. `Dim Valore As Integer = e.Argument`

Comment: Grazie. Non sono sicuro di capire. Come posso fare per ottenere che bworker(0) faccia pagina(0) ecc.? Però non fa niente perché il mio sistema funziona.

Comment: Non vedo il vantaggio di memorizzare tutti i controlli usando gli array. Non ti basta un indice per sapere quale Form creare di volta in volta?

Comment: Forse continuare con chat se vuoi? Io non posso iniziare il chat e per oggi ho finito.

Comment: Nemmeno io posso perchè dobbiamo entrambi avere una reputazione maggiore o uguale a 20. Comunque, se non ti interessa più di tanto ti auguro buon proseguimento su Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The problem I had with the e.Argument system was that it only applied to DoWork. I use RunWorkerCompleted to show the form created (if I try to show it with DoWork things go badly wrong). RunWorkerCompleted has no e.Argument property. My solution is to do this: e.Result = e.Argument in DoWork because e.Result is available in RunWorkerCompleted.

Comment: You can show the Form during `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` by using [`Form.ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: But I have to show many forms more or less simultaneously. Their opacity is changed from 0 to 1 when they need to be seen. So ... Comunque grazie!