# How to check background worker is Is busy or not?

Tags: vb.net

In dynamic background worker code and how to check the background worker is busy or not?

```
For Each value In intersect
    NumWorkers = NumWorkers + 1
    Workers(NumWorkers) = New BackgroundWorker
    Workers(NumWorkers).WorkerReportsProgress = True
    Workers(NumWorkers).WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    AddHandler Workers(NumWorkers).DoWork, AddressOf WorkerDoWork
    Workers(NumWorkers).RunWorkerAsync(value)
    AddHandler Workers(NumWorkers).RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted
Next
```

Comment: [`BackgroundWorker.IsBusy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.isbusy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: In the dynamic background worker we can't check it as backgroundworkername .isbusy., Any other solution

Comment: What do you mean by *"dynamic"*? Being an element in an array? You should still be able to call `IsBusy`. How about `If Workers(bwIndex).IsBusy Then ...`?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile with that `Workers(NumWorkers)` line.

Comment: I have tried Workers(bwIndex).IsBusy but shows an error object reference is empty ?

Comment: You should have posted your code came from this answer: [How to dynamically create a background worker in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552757/719186)