# Dynamically creating multiple background workers and passing them arguments

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2015, backgroundworker, ping

I've written an app that basically does constant pings to a list of hosts and logs the results.

I have a function...

```
 Public Function doping(ByRef host As String)

    Dim Result As Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply
    Dim SendPing As New Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    Dim ResponseTime As Long
    Dim timestamp As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    Try
        Result = SendPing.Send(host, 300)
        ResponseTime = Result.RoundtripTime

        If Result.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
            DynaLogging(timestamp & " - Reply from " & host & ": bytes=32 time=" & ResponseTime.ToString & " TTL=??", host & ".log")
            TextBox2.Text = timestamp & " - Reply from " & host & " : time =" & ResponseTime.ToString & br & TextBox2.Text
        Else
            DynaLogging(timestamp & " - No reply received from " & host, host & ".log")
            TextBox2.Text = timestamp & " - No reply received from " & host & br & TextBox2.Text
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

And I've got a timer, which currently fires off the following in a background worker...

```
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each hostyhost As String In ListBox1.Items
      doping(hostyhost)

  Next
```

This works a treat until one of the hosts in the list is not responding, then the backgroundworker waits because it can only process one ping at a time and so if one host is delayed, the remaining hosts have to wait before they are checked and the whole process slows down.

I could do with somehow dynamically creating multiple background workers at runtime but I do not know how to create a background worker dynamically which can be passed an argument.

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376972/how-to-dynamically-create-a-background-worker-in-vb-net?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) about creating bgw's at runtime, but have no idea how to deploy this for what I need.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next`?  Don't do that.  You know about BackgroundWorker, so give it a try.  Post a question regarding that if you have problems.  This question is too broad.

Comment: I used to use Try for this, but on a post a while back someone said 'If your using a for each, dont use try; use on error resume next ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I did try making it work with backgroundworker myself before posting, but i get errors stating the background worker couldnt handle multiple concurrent items and was busy.  :(  I dont think its too broad.

Comment: The post you made is too broad.  The stuff in your comments, if you posted it in your question with the code, would put it back on track.  The hint here is: you need multiple background workers, or async/await.  And the On Error Resume Next was bad advice: it hides what's going wrong.

Comment: Ok, hows that edit @LarsTech?

Comment: Why create your own threads when you can take advantage of the `Ping.SendAsync()` method? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40820084/3740093

Comment: I tried this also, but it wouldnt  go through, throwing up 'Expression does not produce a value'. :(

Comment: You're likely targeting a too old .NET version and/or using a too old VS version. On which line(s) do you get the error?

Comment: Literally on this line 'Result = SendPing.SendAsync(host, 100)'  -  I'm Targeting .net 4.5 using VS2015

Comment: I thought you meant the code from my answer. Please see the link I shared in my first comment. It requires a little tweaking to work the way you want it to, but it should give you an insight of how `SendAsync()` works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169112/discussion-between-john-and-visual-vincent).

Answer (score 1):

Why not a [Parallel ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)?

```
Dim Items As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
        Items.Add(item.ToString())
    Next

Parallel.ForEach(Items, Sub(hostyhost)
    doping(hostyhost)
End Sub)
```

It's included in the .NET Framework 4.0 under the [System.Threading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace and will take care of almost everything, without writing a million lines of code.

Comment: Can you elaborate for me? I've switched out my for each for your parallel.foreach and I've got errors all over the place.

Comment: Yes I will, would you tell me what errors are you getting, so I know where to start from?

Comment: I have two 'Declaration expected' and one 'End sub should be matched with a preceding sub.

Comment: did you remove `On Error Resume Next` and `Next`?

Comment: @John : Are you targeting .NET 4.0 or higher and using Visual Studio 2010 or higher?

Comment: @FrancescoB. Yes i did, I tried it a few different ways around too.

Comment: Just one error now... Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ForEach' can be called with these arguments

Comment: @John What if you change the second line to `doping(hostyhost.ToString())` ?

Comment: Sadly no change :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169113/discussion-between-john-and-francesco-b).